# Using double references in c++

Tags: c++, list, pass-by-reference

I'm working in C++ with lists and I happen to need to use a double reference.
I need a list (defined in main() ) to be used by a function called by another function, and I don't manage to get it working.
I attach a piece of code as example.

Could anybody give me some help?

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <list>

    using namespace std;

    void aux(list<int>&);
    void aux_(list<int>&); //?

    main()
    {
        list <int> lista;
        aux(lista);
    }

    void aux(list<int>& li)
    {
        aux_(li); //?
    }

void aux_(list<int>&lis) //?
{
    list <int>::const_iterator it;
    while(it!=lis.end())
    {
        cout<<*it<<" ";
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler - your iterator `it` is uninitialized.

Comment: What is your definition of a "double reference"?

Comment: I am voting to close. The problem is caused by a simple mistake, and has nothing to do with references, "double" or not.

Comment: I think it refers to forwarding twice a reference argument wich is not the problem, In general "fix my code" questions are not proper questions here, the answer to that is already spread over dozen of similiar questions. However that' your first question so I'll skip over that for now, don't forget to accept my answer (if that fix your problem) and wellcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you not initialized the iterator, you should do

```
list <int>::const_iterator it = lis.begin();
```

as you see now [the code is working](http://ideone.com/3G4sCM)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I thought it had something to do with double && or &*, but that's not at all necessary, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use iterators, yes, or you could use the much simpler range-based `for`<sup>since C++11</sup>:

```
void aux_(const list<int>& lis)
{
    for(int i : lis) // "for each int in lis, do the following:"
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

And also as a good practice, pass `lis` as `const` since you're not modifying it.

Comment: I wasn't taught about this way of doing it, thanks!